# How make a complete login throuth facebook in an android app in server side

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I have been looking for information about this, but I can't find what I'm looking for exactly. I would like to add a Facebook Login button in my app in Android. I have seen some tutorials, and the authentication in android works, I can get the data from the user. But I would like to save any data from the user in the database to identify it. 
My doubts are,

Is it enough with the authentication made in the app, or I need to save some data in the server to check it and authenticate to the user?

Is it secure just save the user_id in the server to identify the user in the requests that the app make to the database?

In the case it is necessary authenticate in server, what is the exactly way to do it?

I would thank if someone can explain me this server side part of the login process in Android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you tell me what kind of app you have made? so i can give you a perfect flow for this.

Comment: The app should save in the database a user_Id and the name of the user at minimum. The app show to the user new content everyday. The user save this content, and in the app can see all the content saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so according to your description of app i am suggest you to save the `user_id , name` of the user.

So now what you have to do is :

```
1) Create a database with appropriate fields.
2) When user login through facebook at that time fetch all the required data like user_id , name etc.
3) Now When you get all information after that check with the database -> if the user_id is saved or not.
4) If no user_id is found then call the insert query.
5) If you find that user_id in database then redirect that user to other activity.
```

And for server you can go with the trusted and secure server providers. and make the database with strongest password so you can secured from hacking.

Let me know if you have any confusion for this. :-)

Comment: Thanks :) So, I don't have to add any kind of password. I have read about access token, and I thought it has any use in the flow. What do you think about it?

Comment: Your welcome. If you are giving login only with facebook then you dont need to save password for that.

Comment: You can accept my answer, if you are satisfy with my answer.
Thanks :-)